How to fix "Google Play is linked to another account" in Bomber Friends?
I'm getting this error in Bomber Friends  on Android when attempting to link to my Google account, how can I fix it?

Google Play is linked to another account


I don't understand because if my Google Play is linked to another account, then I'd expect that other account to load right after I link my Google account.

Click on switch account:

Then link Google:

